# Javascript Callback function after download Excel

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I need to send mail to user after downloading .csv file. I am not sure how to set callback function after file gets downloaded.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetAllCustomer", "Customers")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { 'customerIds': strCustomerId },
    success: function (result) {
        if (result == "Success") {
            location.href = '@Url.Action("DownloadFile", "Customers", new { extension = "csv"})';
        } else {
            toastLast = toastr.error("No data found", "Generating File");
        }
    }
});
```

In above code in first call i am getting all the customers. On success callback i am calling DownloadFile method to download csv file. i have requirement to send mail after downloading file but i am not sure how will i know that file is downloaded. Or Can I achieve with some other way.

Please find my DownloadFile method of controller as below.

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile(string extension)
    {
        var dateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("M.dd.yy");
        var fileName = dateTime + " Application File." + extension;
        var array = TempData["Output"] as byte[];
        if (array != null)
        {
            var file = File(array, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
            return file;
        }
        else
        {
            return new EmptyResult();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use this line

```
    location.href = '@Url.Action("DownloadFile", "Customers", new { extension = "csv"})';
```

Instead use a ajax request to the Action method

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",  
        url: '@Url.Action("DownloadFile", "Customers")',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(){ 
            //add your sccuess handlings
        }
        error: function(){
            //handle errors
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes you are correct. I've add the complete working codes in the following git repo https://github.com/sajithawattage/Code-Snippet/tree/master/FileDownloadAjax